# What is the most efficient way to handle "hg import" rejects?

Tags: mercurial

When I import a patch using `hg import`, the command sometimes creates .rej files.

When a conflict occurs, is there a way to automatically launch the visual merge tool instead of creating the .rej files?

If not, what is the most efficient workflow to process the .rej files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite the answer you're looking fo,r but ideally you avoid the `.rej` files by improving your workflow to avoid the need to use `import`.

Here are some common uses for `import` and better alternatives for each case:

- **cherry picking** - when you're using `import` (or `transplant` which is just export followed by `import`) to move changes from one branch to another without moving everything else on that branch you could instead be using `merge` if you had been more careful about what the parent of that changeset-to-move was.  Hindsight is 20/20, of course, but when possible do a `hg update` to the *earliest possible parent* of the change you're making (ex: fix bugs in a child changeset of the changeset that introduced the bug) then then only ancestors of the fix is a changeset that exists anywhere the bug exists, and you save safely `pull` and `merge` it wherever the bug exists without bringing anything with it -- or needed `import`.
- **submitted patches** - if possible get people working in mercurial clones from which you can `pull`.  Then you'll only need to `merge` in their work.

There's nothing wrong with `import` but when possible prefer a `pull` and `merge` and with a little foresight you can usually make that possible.

Comment: I agree.  You cannot properly launch a diff tool with a .rej file alone, or with a patch for that matter.  There just isn't enough information there. What you really need to know is what particular changeset the patch is supposed to be applied against.  Then you could theoretically write a script to present a merge.